# Tap Win Adapter installs every start of Win 8.1 a new TAP adapter apears

Tags: windows, vpn, boot, adapter

I have a problem since nearly 2 or 3 month now.
Every time I start win 8.1 64 Bit a new Tap Win32 Adapter OAS and a V9 Tap adapter appears in the system and my internet is getting worse.

Can somebody help please?!

Comment: What software do you have installed on your OS? OpenVPN? Any other VPN software? Any Virtualization software?

Answer (score 0):

Those adapters come with Cyberghost VPN. First you must be sure that you delete Cyberghost completely from your computer, then go to `Network and Sharing Center` or `device manager`  and disable those adapters. You can easily remove them from `device manger` and just restart to have it take affect.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following and they will disappear

1. Win+R -> Type in "msinfo32" press Enter.
2. Now you will see the following Console Window.
   [image: MSinfo32 console]
3. In the left pane navigate to components ->Network -> Adapter
4. Here, you can see all the Network Adapters listed
5. Find the TAP adapters and see the Driver location as shown in the below image
   [image: Location of TAP adapter driver]
6. I have given a sample image as I have already deleted the TAP adapters. Don't delete the Microsoft Adapters.
7. Find the Tap adapters location in listed adapters & go to the location for example: `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\TAP.sys` and delete them.
8. Go to to Device Management and uninstall the TAP adapters under Network Adapters.

Note: While uninstalling, tick the option "Delete the Driver" if asked for a prompt.

Answer (score -1):

I have finally found a solution...i have downloaded program called Process monitor
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

And tried to find which process creates the file tap0901.sys
And there it was...

in C:\Windows\Temp

i had some kind of mallware that had a script for creating these damn TAP9 adapters...i deleted it and it's gone now!

C:\Windows\AutoKMS\AutoKMS.exe is the process which creates the InstallTAPAdapter.exe and it needs to be deleted!

Comment: This does not answer the author's question, I can confirm as a Windows 10 user, that the existing answer does work.  You can edit this answer, all you want, it still isn't an answer to this author's question.

Comment: Ninja edit! Not changing my vote... AutoKMS isn't malware it's used to activate pirated versions of Windows!  So your using a pirated copy of Windows if it exists on your machine